# Не могу подключить vue-router в Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue-router

не получается подключить "vue-router": "^3.5.2" в "Laravel 10".
Когда я в "index.blade.php" через "", подключаю главный компонент "Index.vue", который является входной точкой для моего приложения. В "Index.vue" через  подключаю router.js который должен подключить все компоненты, но он их не подгружает. Помогите разобраться, снизу я привожу код по порядку, чтобы было понятно
web.php выглядит так:

```
Route::get('/{page}', [IndexController::class, '__invoke'])
```

IndexController.php выглядит так:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
public function __invoke()
{
return view('index');
 }
}
```

index.blade.php выглядит так:

```
@extends('shabloni.maket')

@section('name-document')
    Пробник
@endsection
@include('shabloni.header.header')
@include('glavnoe_menu.menu')

<div id="app">
    <Index></Index>
</div>
```

Index.vue выглядит так:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Index"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

router.js закомментировал Vue.use(VueRouter), т.к перестаёт работать, поэтому выглядит так:

```
import './bootstrap';
import PostComponent from "./components/PostComponent.vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// Vue.use(VueRouter)



export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/posts', component: PostComponent
        }
    ]
})
```

app.js выглядит так:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import './bootstrap';
import router from "./router"
import Index from "./components/Index.vue";

// ***Подключаем элемент и остальные библиотеки***
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'

//***Здесь будем импортировать компоненты***
import FormaComponent from "./components/Test/FormaComponent.vue";

const app = createApp({
    el: '#app',

    //***Здесь будем подключать компоненты***
    components:{
        'forma-component': FormaComponent,
        Index
    },

    router
});

app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount('#app');
```

PostComponent.vue выглядит так:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Post component
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PostComponent"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, решён установкой vue-router@4